# Incomplete response received from application even after adding secret_key_base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rvm, passenger

I am using nginx with passenger
I am getting the error as below.

> Incomplete response received from application

In my nginx error.log the error is

> App 6034 stderr: [ 2017-08-26 03:11:29.5981
>   6125/0x00000001e4a920(Worker 1) utils.rb:87 ]: *** Exception TypeError
>   in Rack response body object (wrong argument type Array (expected
>   Struct)) (process 6125, thread 0x00000001e4a920(Worker 1))

In my rails application log there are no errors and also request is completed with status 200

Please help me finding the solution

Comment: are you getting this error in development or production ?

Comment: error in production

Comment: Can you post the entire exception backtrace?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: It got solved. Error was that the nginx was using wrong passenger module(different ruby version). Thanks